# Multiple divs next to each that scale with the browser

Tags: html, css, list

Ok, here goes.

So I have 3  that are to represent 3 blocks of content next to each other.

I want them to scale to the browser whilst keeping their aspect ratio.

This is what I have so far:

```
.dash__node__container {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
  position: absolute;
 } 

.dash__node {
  width: 32.75%;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
  position: relative;
}
```

And Html:

```
<div class="dash__node__container">
      <div class="dash__node"></div>
      <div class="dash__node"></div>
      <div class="dash__node"></div>
    </div>
```

This code isn't holding the aspect ratio and the third block jumps down to the next line.

EDIT: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ogRyoO

Comment: I think the term "keeping their aspect ratio" may confuse people.  You want the three `.dash__node` blocks to remain on a single line regardless of the screen width.  To do this, you want each `.dash__node` to have a flexible width.

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: Yes, thats correct. But they do have a flexible width?

Comment: @Paulie_D How are you? Its long time see you on overflow.. :)

Comment: Been away on another project..back now.

Comment: I see; I am also not so active anymore on SO occasionally come on SO now.. Since last 2 days i am here.. but glad to see you here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `float: left;` to keep the divs from breaking apart and use the padding-bottom trick instead of height to keep an aspect ratio.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.dash__node__container {
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 75%;
  position: absolute;
 } 

.dash__node {
  float: left;
  width: 32.75%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
  border: 1px solid #D8D8D8;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add float:left; to dash__node class, and remove position:relative;

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline-block and add float:left

Answer (score 0):

That is because you use `display: inline-block`. Use `float: left;`

Answer (score 0):

You could use `float:left` but another alternative is to have `font-size:0` in your wrapper. This eliminates the space between your blocks. Obviously you'll then need to apply a font size to your child nodes. [More info here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

The third block element falls below at smaller screen sizes because you have padding on your wrapper. Applying `box-sizing:border-box;`to all your divs will sort this. [More on that here](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).

Here's a fiddle with the above applied: https://jsfiddle.net/nf7wsmk4/

Comment: There was time when I also use `font-size:0` to achieve desire effect. but there are some drawbacks of using.  may be some senior people can show some light why not to use `font-size:0`

Comment: In the link I added it mentions that this will have issues on Android devices if they are pre-Jellybean OR if you're sizing your fonts using ems.